# Multiple BroadcastReceivers that handle the BOOT_COMPLETED action?

Tags: android

Is it possible to have multiple BroadcastReceivers that run on BOOT_COMPLETED in a single app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but there would be no reason for this, as you could simply have them all in one BroadcastReceiver.

Since each one will run, ON_BOOT_COMPLETED, it'll produce the same result, without being a system-hog.

Comment: I do have a valid reason: an external library needing this flag + my app directly needing this flag.